# Adding a field in DaemonSet returns "Unknown field "nodeAffinity" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSet"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Using KubeEdge and I'm attempting to prevent my edgenode from getting kube-proxy deployed.

When I attempt to add fields to daemonsets.apps with the following command:

```
 sudo kubectl edit daemonsets.apps -n kube-system kube-proxy
```

With the following values

```
affinity:
 nodeAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
          - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/edge
            operator: DoesNotExist
```

Returns the following error:

```
# daemonsets.apps "kube-proxy" was not valid:
# * <nil>: Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": ValidationError(DaemonSet): unknown field "nodeAffinity" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSet
#
```

The full YAML for reference:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-03-10T21:02:16Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-proxy
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "458"
  uid: 098d94f4-e892-43ef-80ac-6329617b670c
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kube-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
        - --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
        - --hostname-override=$(NODE_NAME)
        env:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.23.4
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kube-proxy
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/kube-proxy
          name: kube-proxy
        - mountPath: /run/xtables.lock
          name: xtables-lock
        - mountPath: /lib/modules
          name: lib-modules
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      priorityClassName: system-node-critical
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: kube-proxy
      serviceAccountName: kube-proxy
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: kube-proxy
        name: kube-proxy
      - hostPath:
          path: /run/xtables.lock
          type: FileOrCreate
        name: xtables-lock
      - hostPath:
          path: /lib/modules
          type: ""
        name: lib-modules
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
status:
  currentNumberScheduled: 1
  desiredNumberScheduled: 1
  numberAvailable: 1
  numberMisscheduled: 0
  numberReady: 1
  observedGeneration: 1
  updatedNumberScheduled: 1
affinity:
nodeAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
          - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/edge
            operator: DoesNotExist
```

Other answers suggested it was a formatting issue, but I've ran it through a YAML validator and it said it was valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`affinity` should be placed under the pod template. Try:

```
spec:
  ...
  template:
  ...
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/edge
                operator: DoesNotExist
      containers:
      - command:
        - /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked: 


`daemonset.apps/kube-proxy edited`